# PySpark multi join on column names as values

Tags: join, pyspark

I have a dataset A

| ACCDES | ACIDYR | ACLAS | BMOP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RA | TIX | 123221 | TA |
| RA | TIX | 123221 | TA |
| KE | TIX | 123221 | TA |
| KE | TIX | 123221 | TA |
| KE | REP | 987898 | TA |
| KE | REP | 987898 | TA |
| ON | REP | 987898 | TA |
| ON | REP | 987898 | TA |
| ON | MOS | 987898 | TA |
| ON | MOS | 6756 | DE |
| RA | MOS | 6756 | DE |

this dataset I need to enhance with multiple sdl_id col from second dataset B

| domain_name | sdl_id | domain_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACCDES | 100012 | RA |
| ACCDES | 100014 | KE |
| ACCDES | 100015 | ON |
| ACCDES | 100017 | BE |
| ACCDES | 100018 | LO |
| ACCDES | 100019 | TE |
| ACCDES | 1005313 | NA |
| ACCDES | 1005314 | KA |
| ACIDYR | 1005316 | TIX |
| ACIDYR | 1005317 | REP |
| ACIDYR | 1005318 | MOS |
| ACIDYR | 1005319 | JIS |
| ACIDYR | 1005320 | DEF |
| ACIDYR | 1005321 | LIP |
| ACIDYR | 1005324 | KER |
| ACIDYR | 1005325 | NOS |
| ACLAS | 1006537 | 123221 |
| ACLAS | 1006538 | 987898 |
| ACLAS | 1007631 | 6756 |
| BMOP | 1009015 | TA |
| BMOP | 1009016 | DE |

need to join it with the following condition:

```
B.domain_name = {A_col_name} && A.{A_col_name} == B.domain_code
```

and take sdl_id column with prefix of the A columns (e.g. ACCDES_sdl_id). So the result will looks like:

| ACCDES | ACIDYR | ACLAS | BMOP | ACCDES_sdl_id | ACIDYR_sdl_id | ACLAS_sdl_id | BMOP_sdl_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RA | TIX | 123221 | TA | 100012 | 1005316 | 1006537 | 1009015 |
| RA | TIX | 123221 | TA | 100012 | 1005316 | 1006537 | 1009015 |
| KE | TIX | 123221 | TA | 100014 | 1005316 | 1006537 | 1009015 |
| KE | TIX | 123221 | TA | 100014 | 1005316 | 1006537 | 1009015 |
| KE | REP | 987898 | TA | 100014 | 1005317 | 1006538 | 1009015 |
| KE | REP | 987898 | TA | 100014 | 1005317 | 1006538 | 1009015 |
| ON | REP | 987898 | TA | 100015 | 1005317 | 1006538 | 1009015 |
| ON | REP | 987898 | TA | 100015 | 1005317 | 1006538 | 1009015 |
| ON | MOS | 987898 | TA | 100015 | 1005318 | 1006538 | 1009015 |
| ON | MOS | 6756 | DE | 100015 | 1005318 | 6756 | 1009016 |
| RA | MOS | 6756 | DE | 100012 | 1005318 | 6756 | 1009016 |

My first thought was to loop columns of A and join B like this:

```
for c in A.columns:
    A = A.join(B.filter(col("domain_name") == c), col(c) == col("domain_code"), "left") \
        .select(A["*"], B["sdl_id"].alias(c + '_sdl_id'))
return A
```

but I am getting error of column sdl_id is ambiguous. I guess there must be some more sophisticated method of joining without looping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drop the duplicated columns after the join.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test1.csv', sep='\t', header=True)
df2 = spark.read.csv('test2.csv', sep='\t', header=True)

cols = df1.columns

def join(df, c):
  return df \
    .join(df2, (f.col('domain_name') == f.lit(c)) & (f.col('domain_code') == f.col(c)), 'left') \
    .withColumnRenamed('sdl_id', c + '_sdl_id') \
    .drop('domain_name', 'domain_code')

for c in cols:
  df = join(df, c)

df.show(truncate=False)

+------+------+------+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|ACCDES|ACIDYR|ACLAS |BMOP|ACCDES_sdl_id|ACIDYR_sdl_id|ACLAS_sdl_id|BMOP_sdl_id|
+------+------+------+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|RA    |TIX   |123221|TA  |100012       |1005316      |1006537     |1009015    |
|RA    |TIX   |123221|TA  |100012       |1005316      |1006537     |1009015    |
|KE    |TIX   |123221|TA  |100014       |1005316      |1006537     |1009015    |
|KE    |TIX   |123221|TA  |100014       |1005316      |1006537     |1009015    |
|KE    |REP   |987898|TA  |100014       |1005317      |1006538     |1009015    |
|KE    |REP   |987898|TA  |100014       |1005317      |1006538     |1009015    |
|ON    |REP   |987898|TA  |100015       |1005317      |1006538     |1009015    |
|ON    |REP   |987898|TA  |100015       |1005317      |1006538     |1009015    |
|ON    |MOS   |987898|TA  |100015       |1005318      |1006538     |1009015    |
|ON    |MOS   |6756  |DE  |100015       |1005318      |1007631     |1009016    |
|RA    |MOS   |6756  |DE  |100012       |1005318      |1007631     |1009016    |
+------+------+------+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```